# Changing header color

Tags: vmware-clarity

New to clarity and I'm trying out the header class `<header class="header header-5">`

Is it possible to add a custom background color `#F7941E` for the header? 
Can I override the color in my Angular component's CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the styles yourself for anything in Clarity, you just add your own styles to your application. Do note, that styles added inside of a component are not global and may not always apply depending on the specificity of your styles.

```css
.header-5 {
  background-color: #F7941E;
}
```